# How to not "fire and forget" when doing a remote trigger of a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bamboo

I am attempting to trigger a parameterized Jenkins build from Bamboo, doing the below:

> POST - 
>   `http://jenkins-url.com/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?ENVIRONMENT=dev&APPLICATION=hello-world`

But I will get a 201 instantly which tells me that the build was created. How do I make this request wait and return the success status of the build instead of the fire and forget?

It is apparently possible as per [Parameterized-Remote-Trigger-Plugin](https://github.com/morficus/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger-Plugin):

[image]

Edit:
created this in the end if you need it.
https://github.com/owenmorgan/jenkins-remote-builder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created the [jenkins-remote-builder](https://github.com/owenmorgan/jenkins-remote-builder) script which will follow your remote build to completion.

Some more details about it (from its [README.md](https://github.com/owenmorgan/jenkins-remote-builder/blob/master/README.md)):

> ### Example
>
> ```
> jenkins=https://user:pass@jenkins.mydomain.com:8080
> jenkins_job=MyApp-Deploy
>
> environment=dev
> application=myapp
> revision=9fd71f63b351b8208264daf86d292ced580a2f60
>
> ./jenkins_remote_trigger.sh \
>             -h ${jenkins} \
>             -j ${jenkins_job} \
>             -p "ENVIRONMENT=${environment}&APPLICATION=${application}&REVISION=${revision}"
> ```
>
> ### Usage:
>
> ```
> -h HOST     | --host=HOST                       Jenkins host
> -j JOBNAME  | --jobname=test-build-job          The name of the jenkins job to trigger
> -p JOBPARAM | --jobparam=environment=uat&test=1 Jenkins job paramiters
> -q          | --quiet                           Don't output any status messages
> ```

Comment: A bit a summary on how it works would be better ;)

Comment: Please review the edit I applied to your (interesting!) answer, but which I think did have a risk of getting deleted (via moderation) because it was pretty much a link-only answer (as indicated somehow by the comment from @Tensibai also).

Answer (score 5):

When setting up the remote trigger, you have to click "Block until the remote triggered projects finish their builds."

[image: Remote Parameterized Job]

Comment: thanks, i may have the wrong end of the stick.. that plug in seems to be for triggering remote builds from jenkins itself? In my scenario, the build is triggered from a request from Bamboo, but we would like that request to hold until the build completes and return the state of the build.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Unfortunately I don't think the API works that way, if you look at how that plugin for Jenkins is developed you'll see it triggers the remote job and then polls for status until it's finished.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up making this https://github.com/owenmorgan/jenkins-remote-builder

Comment: @osmorgan: you should describe that in an answer (with a bit of summary, not only the link) and accept it.

Comment: sheesh.. its in the question.. and there is a description in the link. see you at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to trigger a job from CLI and wait for its completion you can use "Jenkins CLI" (see [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/228392127-How-to-wait-for-build-to-finish-when-triggering-from-CLI-)).

However jenkins CLI does not support promotions so for them I came up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Trigger a promotion and wait for its completion
#
# For triggering jobs jenkins cli is sufficient: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/228392127-How-to-wait-for-build-to-finish-when-triggering-from-CLI-
#
# The script is dependent on the current jenkins implementation of:
# - the promotion web page (links for triggering/re-executing the promotions)
# - the behaviour of the XML of the promotion status
#
# The behaviour of the job run status XML is:
#   - if the the promotion is not yet been triggered than the response is 404 not found
#   - is the the promotion has been triggered
#     - ... but it's still waiting for an executor:  the response is 404 not found or <duration> is empty
#     - ... and has started:                         <duration> is empty or 0
#     - ... and it's finished:                       <duration> is a non-zero number
#
#
#  run syntax:
#    ./trigger_promotion_and_wait_for_completion.sh \
#       <job_name> \
#       <job_run_number_to_promote> \
#       <promotion_name> \
#       <jenkins_user> \
#       <jenkins_pwd> \
#       <jenkins_url> \
#       <script_workspace_folder> \
#       '{"name": "prom_param_1", "value": "stringvalue" } , {"name": "prom_param_2", "value": true }'
#
#   example:
#    ./trigger_promotion_and_wait_for_completion.sh \
#       job1 \
#       22 \
#       promotion1 \
#       admin \
#       password \
#       http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ \
#       . \
#       '{"name": "prom_param_1", "value": "stringvalue" } , {"name": "prom_param_2", "value": true }'



set -uexo pipefail

#other debug options:
#PS4='+\t '
#set -v

JOB_NAME="${1}"
JOB_RUN_NUMBER="${2}"
DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME="${3}"
BUILDER_USER="${4}"
BUILDER_PASSWORD="${5}"
JENKINS_URL="${6}"
WORKSPACE_FOLDER="${7}"
PROMOTION_ARGUMENTS="${8}"

TIMEOUT=900


echo "retrieving the promotion nextBuildNumber (so we can poll the promotion status and check if it's finished)..."
PROMOTION_RUN_NUMBER="$( curl -s  -u${BUILDER_USER}:${BUILDER_PASSWORD} "${JENKINS_URL}job/${JOB_NAME}/promotion/process/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/api/xml"  | grep -P  '<nextBuildNumber>(.*)</nextBuildNumber'   | sed -re 's/.*<nextBuildNumber>(.*)<\/nextBuildNumber.*/\1/g' )"




echo "running the promotion..."
echo 'only the first promotion can be triggered with "Approve", while subsequent promotions are triggered with "Re-execute promotion"'
echo 'so we check in the web page if the approve link is present'

#the link to search in the web page
PROMOTION_APPROVE_STRING="promotionProcess/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/promotionCondition/hudson.plugins.promoted_builds.conditions.ManualCondition/approve"

PROM_STATUS_URL="${JENKINS_URL}job/${JOB_NAME}/${JOB_RUN_NUMBER}/promotion/"

if curl -s -vvv -u${BUILDER_USER}:${BUILDER_PASSWORD}  "${PROM_STATUS_URL}" | grep "${PROMOTION_APPROVE_STRING}" ; then
    echo "The job has not yet been promoted, triggering it with 'Approve'"
    WEB_PATH="job/${JOB_NAME}/${JOB_RUN_NUMBER}/promotion/promotionProcess/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/promotionCondition/hudson.plugins.promoted_builds.conditions.ManualCondition/approve"
    SUBMIT="Approve"
else
    echo "The job has already been promoted, triggering it with 'Re-execute promotion'"
    WEB_PATH="job/${JOB_NAME}/${JOB_RUN_NUMBER}/promotion/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/build"
    SUBMIT="Re-execute+promotion"
fi


#note for the troubleshooting: in case the following curl fails then the error cause can be found near the string "stack trace"
CURL_OUTPUT="$(  curl -s -vvv -XPOST -u${BUILDER_USER}:${BUILDER_PASSWORD} "${JENKINS_URL}${WEB_PATH}"  \
                       --data 'json={
                                 "parameter": [
                                                '"${PROMOTION_ARGUMENTS}"'
                                              ]
                                    }&Submit='"${SUBMIT}" 2>&1 )"

if ( echo "${CURL_OUTPUT}" |  grep -P "< HTTP/1.1 5\d\d" ) || ( echo "${CURL_OUTPUT}" |  grep -P "< HTTP/1.1 4\d\d" ) ; then
  echo  'error in triggering the job/promotion! exiting...'
  exit 1
else
  echo  'curl good'
fi



echo "checking promotion status until promotion is finished"
FINISHED=no


INITIAL_TIME="$(date +%s)"
while [ "${FINISHED}" != "ok" ]
do
    sleep 2


    #checking if promotion is finished (we check the value of <duration> XML element in the job run status)
    ERROR="" ; DURATION="$(curl -s  -u${BUILDER_USER}:${BUILDER_PASSWORD} "${JENKINS_URL}job/${JOB_NAME}/${JOB_RUN_NUMBER}/promotion/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/promotionBuild/${PROMOTION_RUN_NUMBER}/api/xml"    | grep -Po  '<duration>.*</duration>'   | sed -re  's/<duration>(.*)<\/duration>/\1/g' )"   || ERROR="yes"
    if [[ $ERROR == "yes" ]] ; then
      echo " the promotion has been queued but not yet started, waiting for it to start..."
      curl -s  -u${BUILDER_USER}:${BUILDER_PASSWORD} "${JENKINS_URL}job/${JOB_NAME}/${JOB_RUN_NUMBER}/promotion/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/promotionBuild/${PROMOTION_RUN_NUMBER}/api/xml"
      ERROR=""
      continue
    fi  ;   ERROR=""




    #we interrupt the polling of the job/promotion status if the promotion
    #  - is terminated
    #  - is taking too long (there is some problem)
    #(in the XML of the job run status the <duration> XML element value is initially empty, than it is 0, and eventually is the number of seconds of the run duration )

    POLLING_TIME="$(date +%s)"
    let "ELAPSED_TIME=POLLING_TIME-INITIAL_TIME"
    echo "ELAPSED_TIME=${ELAPSED_TIME}"

    if  (( ${ELAPSED_TIME} \> $TIMEOUT ))  ; then
      echo "error: the promotion has taken too long... exiting"
      exit 1
    fi

    if  [[ "${DURATION}" != "" ]] ; then
      re='^[0-9]+$'
      if [[ $DURATION =~ $re ]] ; then
        if (( "${DURATION}" \> "0" )) ; then
          FINISHED=ok
        else
          : #do nothing (the value of <duration> is 0 , that is the job/promotion has been started in a slave and is still running)
        fi
      else
        echo "error: the promotion duration is not a number. exiting..."
        exit 1
      fi
    else
      :  # the job/promotion has not yet started
    fi

    echo "waiting for the promotion to finish..."
done

echo "Promotion finished"



echo "Promotion output:"
curl -s  -u${BUILDER_USER}:${BUILDER_PASSWORD} "${JENKINS_URL}job/${JOB_NAME}/${JOB_RUN_NUMBER}/promotion/${DEPLOY_PROMOTION_NAME}/promotionBuild/${PROMOTION_RUN_NUMBER}/consoleText" > ${WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/promotionOutput

cat ${WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/promotionOutput

if [[ ! "$(tail -n1 ${WORKSPACE_FOLDER}/promotionOutput)" =~ "SUCCESS"  ]] ; then
      echo "Promotion did not successfully terminate"
      exit 1
else
      echo "Promotion successfully terminated"
fi
```