# Specifying branch name for jenkins job through AnyStatus

Tags: jenkins, monitoring

I am wondering if anyone else has integrated before a parameterized Jenkins build with [AnyStatus](https://www.anystat.us/).

[image]

When removing the parameter above, I am able to run builds using the branch specified previously from the browser, but that's not the idea. There is a [post](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/457/how-to-not-fire-and-forget-when-doing-a-remote-trigger-of-a-jenkins-build) explaining that I can use a script, but that wouldn't be integrated with AnyStatus in the existing Jenkin's plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I figured it out. I just went to the job configuration, activated the "build is parameterized" checkbox, added a string parameter called BRANCH, and in the "branches to build" section added `${BRANCH}`. Pretty much what is explained here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359810/how-to-trigger-jenkins-builds-remotely-and-to-pass-parameters
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108380/jenkins-how-to-build-a-specific-branch